# Фронт (React) не отправляет запрос на бэк (Spring Boot)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku

Задеплоил фронт-энд (ReactJS) и бек-энд(Spring Boot) как два разных приложения (со своими адресами) на Heroku.
Адрес фронта: *https://front-for-app.herokuapp.com.*
Адрес бэка: *https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com.*
На фронте в файле `**setupProxy.js**` прописал адрес бэка в target:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
 
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

В консоли браузера наблюдаю вот такую ошибку и адрес, по которому уходит запрос:
[image]

Попробовал прописать даже в **package.json** proxy:

```
"proxy": "https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com",
```

Результата нет. Подскажите, как мне перенаправить запросы по адресу бэкенда на Heroku?
С помощью настроек в setupProxy.js успешно обращаюсь к серверу за данными из базы данных даже с локального адреса - с локального приложения фронтенда. А с Heroku не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я выяснил, в чем было дело. Файл `setupProxy.js` только для разработки. Для продакшена нам необходим файл `static.json` в корне проекта.
В моем случае код в нем такой:

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    },
    "proxies": {
        "/api/": {
            "origin": "https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com/api"
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на `/api"` в конце адреса - эта часть очень важная. Ничего не работает без этого `/api"`